# Can I drop off a rucksack of supplies at an outpost instead of a base?

Tags: state-of-decay

In *State of Decay* outposts have supply lockers. Can I place rucksacks of supplies there or do I have to trudge off to a base to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to go back to your home base to drop them off.